# Why is my Firestore call not resolving before going further with the next .then()?

Tags: javascript, firebase, promise, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I thought I had a simple function:

1. database change trigger (.onUpdate)
2. find out which change is possibly important for a notification (prepareNotifications(change))
3. ask firebase if there are records that want a notification about that change (getDatabaseNotifications(changeWithNotification))
4. sent notifications (sentNotifications(changeWithNotification))

I'm stuck for a couple off days now on how to resolve the Firebase call before moving on.

- tried to Promise.all([getDatabaseNotifications()])
- tried to chain this function like this:

```
    changes  
      then firebase call  
         then sent notifiactions
```

What is happening:

1. I get the changes,
2. The call to Firebase is done,
3. But before waiting for the result it moves on to sending notifications.
4. It finds no notifications in Firebase (but there are notifications!)
5. It's gathering the notifications (array [])
6. ... here I push a test notification ...
7. It's sending 1 notification (the test notification)
8. Then it resolves the Firebase notifications (this should be resolved before).
9. Then the function stops without doing anything anymore.

This is how my function looks now.  Can someone explain how I can wait on Firebase?

```
exports.showUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document('shows/{showId}')
    .onUpdate((change, context) => {
      return prepareNotifications(change) // check if and which notifications to get out of the firebase database
        .then(changes => {
          console.log('changes');
          console.log(changes);
          if(changes) {
            const gatherData = [];
            changes.forEach(change => {
              console.log('change');
              console.log(change);
              getDatabaseNotifications(change.showId, change.ring, change.ringNumber) // firebase call
                .then(data => {
                  gatherData.push([...gatherData, ...data]);
                  console.log('gatherData');
                  console.log(gatherData);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                })
            })
            return gatherData;
          }
          return null;
        })
        .then(notifications => {
          console.log('notifications');
          console.log(notifications);
          notifications.push(testData); // add some test notifications
          if (notifications && notifications.length > 0) {
            sentNotifications(notifications); // sent notifications
            return 'sending notifications';
          }
          return 'no notifications to sent';
        })
        .catch(err => {
          Sentry.captureException(new Error(`Showupdate sending notifications not ok. Error message: ${err.message}`));
        })
  });
```

Updated code which works! thanks to your examples.

```
exports.showUpdate = functions.firestore
  .document('shows/{showId}')
  .onUpdate((change, context) => {
    return prepareNotifications(change) // check if and which notifications to get out of the firebase database
      .then(changes => {
        if(changes) {
          return getDbRecords(changes);
        }
      })
      .then(notifications => {
        if (notifications && notifications.length > 0) {
          sentNotifications(notifications); // sent notifications
          return 'sending notifications';
        }
        return 'no notifications to sent';
      })
      .catch(err => {
        Sentry.captureException(new Error(`Showupdate sending notifications not ok. Error message: ${err.message}`));
      })
});

function getDbRecords(changes) {
  const gatherData = [];
  const gatherDataPromises = [];
  changes.forEach(change => {
    gatherDataPromises.push(
      getDatabaseNotifications(change.showId, change.ring, change.ringNumber) // firebase call
        .then(data => {
          gatherData.push(...data);
        })
    );
  });
  return Promise.all(gatherDataPromises)
    .then(() => { return gatherData }
  );
}
```

Comment: TL;DR: you didn't return the promises created by `getDatabaseNotifications` (so it didn't wait for them)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This section of your code doesn't handle promises properly, it creates a bunch of work but then will return `gatherData` before any of it has happened, which is why you don't see any notifications:

```js
         if(changes) {
            const gatherData = [];
            changes.forEach(change => {
              console.log('change');
              console.log(change);
              getDatabaseNotifications(change.showId, change.ring, change.ringNumber) // firebase call
                .then(data => {
                  gatherData.push([...gatherData, ...data]);
                  console.log('gatherData');
                  console.log(gatherData);
                })
                .catch(err => {
                  console.log(err);
                })
            })
            return gatherData;
          }
```

Notably, you probably want that `return gatherData` to be chained off the set of promises that are generated by the entire set of calls to `getDatabaseNotifications`.

Something like:

```
         if(changes) {
            const gatherData = [];
            const gatherDataPromises = [];
            changes.forEach(change => {
              console.log('change');
              console.log(change);
              gatherDataPromises.push(
                getDatabaseNotifications(change.showId, change.ring, change.ringNumber) // firebase call
                  .then(data => {
                    gatherData.push([...gatherData, ...data]);
                    console.log('gatherData');
                    console.log(gatherData);
                  })
              );
            });
            return Promise.all(gatherDataPromises)
              .then(() => { return gatherData });
          }
```

I removed the `catch` statement to allow the error to bubble up to the top level `catch`.

Caution: I have not tested this, as I don't have sample data or the code for `getDatabaseNotifications`, but the general approach should solve your current problem.  Likewise, it allows all the calls to `getDatabaseNotifications` to run in parallel, which should be significantly faster than just awaiting on them in sequence.

That said, you do have other problems in this code -- for example, the `return null` just below the block I am discussing will likely lead you into trouble when you try to use `notifications.push()` in the following `then()` (but this also appears to be test code).

Comment: Might be cleaner with `map` (instead of `forEach`)... you would probably need to move then after the Promise.all.

Comment: Probably, I try to keep answers close to the original code though if I can, especially since without a MCVE I can't test it, and more specifically that I don't know if `changes` is an array in this case, or something that just happens to have a `forEach` method, like a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot.html).  (It pretty clearly isn't a `QuerySnapshot` here though).

Comment: The example was realy helpfull. I know what went wrong with my Promise.all().

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because of the async nature of the methods. So, instead of waiting "getDatabaseNotifications()" to finish it's job, it jumps into ".then(notifications =>{}" and in this case gatherData returns empty.

putting await before calling the method might work.

```
await getDatabaseNotifications(change.showId, change.ring, change.ringNumber)
```

Comment: If you use await for each one, you also need to make the function async (easy) but keep in mind that you would now be serializing the work which could be much slower.  It would be better to await a `Promise.all()` of all of the invocations rather than one at a time (or just use a `.then` off the `Promise.all()` call).

Comment: Yeah, I saw you answer after submitting the answer. I wasn't aware of Promise.all(), thank you for informing :)